# laravel index.php modify for production

Tags: php, laravel, git, production, laravel-7

basically I want to be able to do something like this:

```
if(env('APP_ENV') === 'production'){
    require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
} else {
    require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

however laravel has not booted at this point so not sure how to modify it as env() is not defined. Any other suggestions welcome.

Comment: This codes calling from url or command line?

Comment: this is the basic laravel index.php i have just modified it for what I want to be able to do. found in laravel/public/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you can do this with .env, but I have a workaround for you.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost'){
    require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
} else {
    require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

Comment: this is not with env.

Comment: Please read the answer carefully first, it said its not with .env

Answer (score -1):

-Enable apache mod_env

-Add This line to your .htaccess file

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT staging
```

-get env with this

```
getenv('APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT')
```